# Weird mod_rewrite behavior

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all specific file extensions to the CDN I have setup. Here's what I'm working with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js|txt|wmv|mp4|flv|avi|mov|wmv))$ http://cdn-w.domain.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

For some reason it's only redirecting to (for example http://www.domain.com/images/image.png)

`http://cdn-w.domain.com/image.png`

rather than

`http://cdn-w.domain.com/images/image.png`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js|txt|wmv|mp4|flv|avi|mov|wmv)$ http://cdn-w.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: That was the golden touch. And it shall go in my arsenal of rewrite 1-liners. Thank you sir.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.